# Can you restrict payment options by price point for BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

Does anyone know if you are able to hid payment methods on your Bigcommerce site by price point.
I have a payment option that I do not want visible for users if their cart is less than $50.00.  I have found the articles on how to achieve this with customer groups but that will not be applicable in my use case.

I have not found a solution that I can implement on my site as of yet.